# apache2 is not running on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ltsp-client

I install LAMP in my Ubuntu 14.04 But when I use (`sudo apache2ctl status | grep version`) command it returns:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 101: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: www-browser: not found
'www-browser -dump localhost:80/server-status"' failed.
Maybe you need to install a package providing www-browser or you
need to adjust the APACHE_LYNX variable in /etc/apache2/envvars
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [link](http://www.cafewebmaster.com/apache2ctl-fullstatus-usrsbinapache2ctl-line-119-www-browser-command-not-found) to an answer that helped me. I am running 14.04 and had to install the command-line browser `links` to get rid of this error:

```
sudo apt-get install links
```